# Dropdown is not holding the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Im using a MVC application which includes jquery 1.9.1 and jquery custom 1.9.2. Previously my application was running on jquery 1.4 and now im upgrading to above mentioned version.

After the upgrade, everything seems to be working fine except for all the dropdowns in the application.

For example, see the below country dropdown before changing the country.

[image]

Once I click on this dropdown, it populates the list

[image]

As you can see from the above list, I placed my mouse over "Australia" and I clicked it. Ideally now "Australia" should be selected in the dropdown but it is not, it still shows "Ameracia Samoa".

Sometimes it works and most of the time it will not work. And Im not facing this issue while using keyboard for selecting the country.

There are no errors in the console, there are no function bound on the dropdown. I suppose jquery could be causing this issue, because while using the older version of jquery I did not face this issue.

Im using only IE 10 browser and I can't verify in any other browser.

Comment: can you show some code snippets that you have tried..

Comment: I haven't written any code for this. This is an existing application and I just upgraded the jquery. All I did was, removed old jquery 1.4 and custom jquery 1.7.3 and included jquery 1.9 and custom jquery 1.9.2.

Comment: I think you should show us a link to your fiddle if you have one